# Multi-Step Build Failure with Docker in Symfony project

Tags: php, docker, dockerfile

**Hi there, I have an error like this while building the Dockerfile:**

### => ERROR [stage-0 15/22] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y $buildDeps --no-install-recommends     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lis  4.7s

> [stage-0 15/22] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y $buildDeps --no-install-recommends     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*     && docker-php-ext-install -v     && apt-get install -y        pdo         pdo_mysql         sockets         intl         zip         xml         curl         json         opcache:

0.785 Hit:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease

0.849 Get:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates InRelease [52.1 kB]

0.969 Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security InRelease [48.0 kB]

1.147 Get:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security/main amd64 Packages [57.6 kB]

1.216 Fetched 158 kB in 1s (246 kB/s)

1.216 Reading package lists...

1.792 Reading package lists...

2.318 Building dependency tree...

2.457 Reading state information...

2.653 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

4.256 getopt: invalid option -- 'v'

4.256 usage: /usr/local/bin/docker-php-ext-install [-jN] [--ini-name file.ini] ext-name [ext-name ...]

4.256    ie: /usr/local/bin/docker-php-ext-install gd mysqli

4.256        /usr/local/bin/docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql

4.256        /usr/local/bin/docker-php-ext-install -j5 gd mbstring mysqli pdo pdo_mysql shmop
4.256

4.256 if custom ./configure arguments are necessary, see docker-php-ext-configure
4.256

4.256 Possible values for ext-name:

4.303 bcmath bz2 calendar ctype curl dba dl_test dom enchant exif ffi fileinfo filter ftp gd gettext gmp hash iconv imap intl json ldap mbstring mysqli oci8 odbc opcache pcntl pdo pdo_dblib pdo_firebird pdo_mysql pdo_oci pdo_odbc pdo_pgsql pdo_sqlite pgsql phar posix pspell readline reflection session shmop simplexml snmp soap sockets sodium spl standard sysvmsg sysvsem sysvshm tidy tokenizer xml xmlreader xmlwriter xsl zend_test zip

4.303
4.303 Some of the above modules are already compiled into PHP; please check

4.303 the output of "php -i" to see which modules are already loaded.Dockerfile:3636

```
  36 | >>> RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y $buildDeps --no-install-recommends \
  37 | >>>     # && apt-get purge -y ${buildRequirements} \
  38 | >>>     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
  39 | >>>     && docker-php-ext-install -v \
  40 | >>>     && apt-get install -y\
  41 | >>>         pdo \
  42 | >>>         pdo_mysql \
  43 | >>>         sockets \
  44 | >>>         intl \
  45 | >>>         zip \
  46 | >>>         xml \
  47 | >>>         curl \
  48 | >>>         json \
  49 | >>>         opcache
```

```
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y $buildDeps --no-install-recommends     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*     && docker-php-ext-install -v     && apt-get install -y        pdo         pdo_mysql         sockets         intl         zip         xml         curl         json         opcache" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

I really want to install the above libraries, I really appreciate your support, thank you.

I have tried many ways but it was the same error, this is the main code from Dockerfile:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y $buildDeps --no-install-recommends \
    # && apt-get purge -y ${buildRequirements} \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && docker-php-ext-install -v \
    && apt-get install -y\
        pdo \
        pdo_mysql \
        sockets \
        intl \
        zip \
        xml \
        curl \
        json \
        opcache
```

Comment: Share the full contents of the *Dockerfile*.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that if you using alpine in your docker file you have to use apk package installer like:

```bash
RUN apk add --update --no-cache pdo pdo_mysql
```

It has a different syntax, You can find an example in this [repo](https://lhttps://github.com/kazemmdev/php-docker):